# DataTable plugin for jquery adds extra space on the bottom of the table body

Tags: javascript, datatables

[image: my table]

Extra zebra line keeps adding to the bottom of my table even though there's enough data to fill the table. More zebra line spaces gets added the more data I have in my table.

I've checked paddings and margin that could possibly do this but I couldn't find it. I believe it has something to do with height but I don't know where to find it.

```
$('#myable').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        "scroller": {
            loadingIndicator: true
        },
        "scrollY": '50vh',
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "deferRender": true

    });
```

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help here.

Comment: The code in your question works fine for me. There must be things you are not showing us.